# Deriving Bessel's Integrals

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to derive the integral form of the Bessel function by finding
the $k$th coefficient of the Laurent series expansion of the function
$f(z) =\exp [\lambda(z-\frac{1}{z})]$.
I managed to get it down to the form

$
J_k(\lambda) =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{i(\lambda \sin\theta - k \theta)} d\theta
=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2 \pi} [\cos(\lambda \sin\theta - k \theta)
+i\sin(\lambda \sin\theta - k \theta)]d\theta
$

But, I need to show that this is equivalent to
$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \cos(\lambda \sin\theta - k \theta)d\theta
$.
In other words, I need to show that
$
\int_{0}^{2 \pi}\sin(\lambda \sin\theta - k \theta)d\theta =0
$

But I can't figure out how to do this. I tried expanding using trig identities and then
writing sin and cos as Taylor Series and integrating term by term, but no luck. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the integral involving $\sin$ as $\int_0^{\pi}$ + $\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}$. Change variable in the second integral as $\phi = \theta - \pi$. Do some trigonometric manipulations like $\sin(\theta + n \pi) = (-1)^n \sin(\theta)$ and you will find that the second integral turns out to be negative of the first.

Comment: Another way to think of the same thing is that the function is antisymmetric about $\pi$ i.e. in the integral if you replace $\alpha = \theta - \pi$, you will find that the resulting integral has an odd integrand and the limits of the integral go from $-\pi$ to $\pi$. So an odd function integrated from $-a$ to $a$ is zero.

Comment: Thanks. I found I didn't have to split the integral, and like you said, I got an odd function integrated from $-\pi$ to $\pi$. However, I'm pretty sure your sample manipulation of $\sin(\theta + n \pi) = \sin \theta$ is only true for even $n$.

Comment: @jake: Right. Thanks for letting me know. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Use $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} f(x)\ dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(a+b-x) \ dx$